# refresh a web service for every 10 minutes

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

i have to refresh the web service for every 10 minutes and i tried with setInterval its not working for me.
here is my code,

```
onActivate:function() 
{
    setInterval(onActivate(),6000);     
    Ext.Ajax.request({
    method:'GET',
    contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType:'json',
    url:'myurl',                                        
    //timeout:6000,
    disableCaching: false,
    interval:6000,
    reader: {
            type: 'json', 
            totalProperty: 'totalcount',
            rootProperty:'GetMobileOperatorListResult',
    },
    success:function(response,request)
    {
            var jsonarr = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            var len=jsonarr.GetMobileOperatorListResult.length;
            console.log("length"+len);
            for(var i=0;i<len;i++)
            {  
                //Storing our values in Array
                var st =  {
                    'text':jsonarr.GetMobileOperatorListResult[i].Operator, 
                    'value':jsonarr.GetMobileOperatorListResult[i].OperatorValue,
                };  
                //Adding our array to LocalStore(localStorage)
                var localStore = Ext.getStore('MobileStore');
                localStore.add(st);                 
                localStore.sync();
                localStore.load();          
            }//for loop
            console.log("operator value\t"+st.value);
            localStore.getProxy().clear();
        },
```

Comment: Just at a quick glance, the line `setInterval(onActivate(),6000);` shouldn't have the `()` after onActivate. Basically, that tells the function to run immediately. What you want to do is provide the function to the setInterval call without the parenthesis so that it can call the function more than once.

Comment: i tried that too.but it returns "onActivate is not defined" as error.

Comment: try `this.onActivate`

Comment: ya...its working fine...thanks a lot for your valuable replies..... :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the ExtJS Polling Provider

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.direct.PollingProvider

```
var poll = new Ext.direct.PollingProvider({
   type: 'polling',
   url: function () {
      Ext.Ajax.request({
         url: 'myurl',
         qualifier: 'Keep Alive',
         success: function (xhr) {
            //do your data processing here
         },
         failure: function () {
         }
      });
   },
   interval: 6000
});

Ext.Direct.addProvider(poll);
```

Comment: FYI - Sencha Touch has the same functionality

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.direct.PollingProvider